# How to save data in localstorage and access it on another html page

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a laundry platform and right now I have 2 HTML page which is booking page and summary page. The booking page is where users can book the number of clothes to be washed using the plus and minus button, this would automatically calculate the total amount to be paid. Now I also want the summary page to display such information as the booking page. This actually mean the information would be stored in localStorage by booking page in order to be accessed by summary page and displayed to users.

```html
<body>
    <div class="second-booking-container">
        <div>
            <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img src="./img/shirt.png" /></div>
            <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" value="100" id="qnty_1">
                Shirt(s)</p>
            <p>
                <button type="button" class="sub" data- target="shirt">-</button>
                <input type="text" value="0" class="field_shirt" />
                <button type="button" class="add" data-target="shirt">+
                </button>

                <p class="display_shirt" name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358;
                    100</p>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img src="./img/trouser.png" /></div>
            <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" value="100" id="qnty_2">
                Trouser(s)</p>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <button type="button" class="sub" data target="trousers">−</button>
                    <input type="text" value="0" class="field_trousers" />
                    <button type="button" class="add" data-target="trousers">+
                    </button>
                    <p class="display_trousers" name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358;
                        0</p>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img src="./img/skirt.png" /></div>
            <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" value="100" id="qnty_3">
                Skirt(s)</p>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <button type="button" class="sub" data- target="skirts">−</button>
                    <input type="text" value="0" class="field_skirts" />
                    <button type="button" class="add" data- target="skirts">+</button>
                    <p class="display_skirts" name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358; 0</p>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img src="./img/blouse.png" /></div>
            <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" value="100" id="qnty_4">
                Blouse(s)</p>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <button type="button" class="sub" data-target="blouses">-
                    </button>
                    <input type="text" value="0" class="field_blouses" />
                    <button type="button" class="add" data-target="blouses">+
                    </button>

                    <p class="display_blouses" name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358;
                        100</p>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img src="./img/jacket.png" /></div>
            <p class="second-booking-container-icon-long" name="product" value="100" id="qnty_5">Suit/Jacket(s)
            </p>
            <p>
                <button type="button" class="sub" data- target="suits">-</button>
                <input type="text" value="0" class="field_suits" />
                <button type="button" class="add" data-target="suits">+
                </button>

                <p class="display_suits" name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358; 100</p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="third-booking-container">
        <p>Total:&#8358; <span id="totalValue"></span></p>
        <button>Set pick up date
            <FontAwesomeIcon class="second-container-button-right" icon="angle-right" /></button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the JS code

```
var subElm = document.querySelectorAll('.sub');
var addElm = document.querySelectorAll('.add');
var totalValueElm = document.getElementById('totalValue');
for (var i = 0; i < subElm.length; i++) {
    subElm[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var targetItem = this.getAttribute('data-target');
        var inputElm = document.querySelector('.field_' + targetItem);
        var displayElm = document.querySelector('.display_' +
            targetItem);
        var currentValue = +inputElm.getAttribute('value');
        if (currentValue !== 0) {
            var incValue = currentValue - 1;
            var strValue = ' ' + incValue;
            inputElm.setAttribute('value', incValue);
            displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358;" + strValue;
            totalValueElm.innerText = Number(totalValueElm.innerText) -
                100;
        }
    });
    addElm[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var targetItem = this.getAttribute('data-target');
        var inputElm = document.querySelector('.field_' + targetItem);
        var displayElm = document.querySelector('.display_' +
            targetItem);
        var currentValue = +inputElm.getAttribute('value');
        var incValue = currentValue + 1;
        var strValue = ' ' + incValue;
        inputElm.setAttribute('value', incValue);
        displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358;" + strValue;
        totalValueElm.innerText = Number(totalValueElm.innerText) +
            100;
    });
}
```

Here is the second html page that I want to also show same information from the previous booking page

```html
<body>
    <div class="summaryContainer">
        <div class="summaryNavBar">
            <p className="summaryTitle">Summary</p>
        </div>
        <div class="summaryContent">
            <p class="total" id="total">Total:</p>
            <p class="sum">&#8358;0.00</p>
        </div>

        <div class="summaryCard">
            <div class="summary-card-title">
                <div>Item</div>
                <div>Quantity</div>
            </div>
            <div class="summary-card-content">
                <div>Shirt(s)</div>
                <div id="
       first" class="summary-quantity"><button type="button" id="sub" class="sub">−</button>
                    <input type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
                    <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="summary-card-content">
                <div>Trouser(s)</div>
                <div class="summary-quantity" id="second">
                    <button type="button" id="sub" class="sub">−</button>
                    <input type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
                    <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="summary-card-content" id="third">
                <div>Suit(s)</div>
                <div class="summary-quantity"><button type="button" id="sub" class="sub">−</button>
                    <input type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
                    <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button> </div>
            </div>
            <p class=" more">..more</p>
        </div>
        <div class="summaryButton">
            <button class="button-left"><span>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon class="buttonLeft" icon="angle-left" /></span>Back</button>
            <button class="button-right">Proceed to
                payment
                <FontAwesomeIcon class="buttonRight" icon="angle-right" /></button>
```

I want all information or data entered by user in booking page to be displayed on summary include each number on the plus and minus button too.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Olaide Kofi. Could you show us your attempt to implement `localStorage` in your website? If you haven't tried yet, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is the documentation on using local storage. Make an attempt and if you get stuck, we can help you out.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for reaching. I have been on this project for weeks now, I tried using localStorage but after setting, I checked the localstorage in console(application) when I tried to get but couldn't fetch it out. KIndly help me out please. I am due for submission too

Comment: It's still a little unclear what the specific problem you are encountering is. There's also a lot of code here to sift through. You might want to read over the guidance on creating a [mcve]. Questions that follow that guidance tend to get answered more

Comment: Hello, sorry for the long code here I believe a pictorial view would be better for this. This is a codepen link for the first page (https://codepen.io/delaquash/pen/gVXyRW) which has the plus and minus button calculating the total and I want that transmitted to the summary page via localstorage https://codepen.io/delaquash/pen/eqdLaa .... Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are having trouble using the [LocalStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) contains detailed examples on how to use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

To set a value:

```
localStorage.setItem('nameOfItem', 'yourValue'); // The value must always be a string
```

And to get a value:

```
let value = localStorage.getItem('nameOfItem');
```

**Note:** since you explain that you are in dire need of a solution, for what I assume is an assignement from your studies, I'll add the next step of code. But do keep in mind, that the solution that you are asking is *not* related to your question. For future references read up on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get your answer faster and better. This will benefit you!

**Addition:** So what you are struggling with is to get your `totalValue` stored in the the `localStorage` whenever, I assume, a user want's to set a pickup date (based on your codepen). This translates to the problem:

> How to store value in localStorage on submit of a form?

So for this to work, you need two things.

- [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) element
- [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) event listener

So why do you need those? The form can be debatable on wether or not you need it. It will enable you to submit all the values in your form without selecting all form elements manually, but can add a bit of complexity if you might just need one value out of all the code. I'll use it for this example so you can utilize the `submit` event of a form.

This `submit` event is fired whenever a `type="submit"` input or button in a form has been clicked. This will be useful in cases where you need to process multiple values simultaneously and do, for example, a validation check on all of the values of the `input` elements.

So wrap a `<form>` element around your code and set an `id` attribute to it. This will make it easy to select it when we need it. Modify the `button` at the end of your form and add `type="submit"` to it. This will make the form submit whenever that button is clicked.

```
<form id="book">

  <!-- Put all the form fields inside here -->

  <button type="submit" name="send">Set pick up date</button>
</form>
```

So, now you've created your form let's go over to the JavaScript side of things.

First thing you'll want to do it is select the form. You gave it an unique `id` so use `document.getElementById` to select it.

```
// Select the form.
var bookForm = document.getElementById('book');
```

Since you now can submit your form listen for the `submit` event on the form to do something whenever your form has been submitted.

Inside your event function get your `totalValue`, the same way that you've done earlier in your code, and store it in a variable.

So now you've got your `totalValue`. From here you can add it to your `localStorage`. See the code below:

```
// Listen for submit event on form.
bookForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  // Get the total value
  var totalValue = totalValueElm.innerHTML;

  // Store the total value in the localStorage.
  localStorage.setItem('totalValue', totalValue);

  // Now redirect to your second page.

  // Prevent form from default submitting.
  // This is important. Removing this line will make the form submit
  // to the server and reload the page.
  event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

You would now have stored your `totalValue` into the `localStorage`. And the value will be overwritten whenever you submit the form again.

So now on your next page you'll want to check if a value is stored in the `localStorage`. This part is explained at the top of my answer, but you'll need to add some checking to it.

```
var totalValue = localStorage.getItem('totalValue');
if (totalValue !== null) { // null is whenever no item of `totalValue` exists.
   // Do something with your value.
}
```

So that's about it. This is as far as I can bring you. If you encounter any more problems try to open up a new thread on SO or ask a peer for help.

I hope you will be able to finish your project.
Best of luck!

Comment: Still didn't it showing on summary page, can you just help me edit the code please and insert the right code. Just a junior developer and this project is my final bootcamp project please.

Comment: You'll want to store the values when you submit your form. I suggest you check out these courses on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form) which will teach you how to use forms. I'm giving you this answer because you are asking multiple questions about writing your code. Do some research, try a new approach and do come back when you have questions about your attempt. You've already gotten this far, you can do it!

Comment: Still did not get it, Can you just help me out. I am late for submission and its my demo project too. Thank you

Comment: Can you please help me make this work, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: @OlaideKofi I've added examples of what you should do, why should do it and how it works. Please read everything carefully, visit the links i've included and don't be afraid to fail. This stuff can be hard to grasp sometimes. Best of luck!